# Need Python stopwords removed and stop phrases? Which order to remove? Can they all be one list of stop words/phrases?

Tags: python, pandas, text, data-cleaning, stop-words

Is it best practice to clean data with stopwords and stop phrases separately?  I have a dataframe below but need specific phrases and specific stopwords removed.

```
import pandas as pd
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
stop = stopwords.words('english')

list_of_phrases_remove = 'I love this asdfasdf car'

stop.append('asdfasdf')

pos_tweets = [('I love this asdfasdf car', 'positive'),
    ('This view is amazing', 'positive'),
    ('I feel great this morning', 'positive'),
    ('I am so excited about the concert', 'positive'),
    ('He is my best friend', 'positive')]

test = pd.DataFrame(pos_tweets)
test.columns = ["tweet","class"]
```

What if I need the stopword "asdfasdf" removed but also need 'I love this asdfasdf car' removed from my list_of_phrases_remove?

What is the order flow for removing stopwords but also specific phrases from a pandas dataframe column of text like this?

Comment: in your example you should start with phrases. And later use stopwords. Don't uses both at the same time. Besides for stopwords you may have to split phrases into list of words.

Comment: I agree with that.  I came to that conclusion last night as well.